# Set currently logged in user as the user in the model when creating an object in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

I've tried to implement the solutions offered by some of the other posts I see on here, but nothing seems to be working. I'm brand new to django and backend in general, so I may just be lacking in skill.

The situation is that I'm letting users generate a `listing` based on a django model `Listings` using a ModelForm. Everything seems to be working except for the fact that I can't set the currently logged in user as the user for the `listing`. I understand that the user is stored in `request.user`, but I can't seem to set it within my form and I consistently get this error:

`IntegrityError at /create`

`NOT NULL constraint failed: auctions_listings.listing_user_id`

Here's the code for my User and Listings model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Listings(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="")
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    image = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    initial_bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="Misc") 
    listing_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listing_user")
    # listing.bid.all()????
```

and here is my form:

```
from .models import Listings

class ListingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Listings
        exclude = ('listing_user')
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'image',
            'initial_bid',
            'category'
        ]
```

Some of the suggestions I've found have figured out that I can excluse the user requirement and then set it myself in my view, but whenever I try to exclude the `listing_user`, I get hit with this error:

`TypeError: ListingsForm.Meta.exclude cannot be a string. Did you mean to type: ('listing_user',)?`

Trying what is suggested is no help either.

Finally, here is my view:

```
def create(request):
    
    form = ListingsForm(request.POST or None)  
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = ListingsForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "auctions/create.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**exclude** should be a **list** or **tuple**. You have two options:

```
exclude = ('listing_user',)
or
exclude = ['listing_user']
```

forms:

```
from .models import Listings

class ListingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Listings
        exclude = ('listing_user',)
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'image',
            'initial_bid',
            'category'
        ]
```

views:

```
def create(request):
    
    form = ListingsForm(request.POST or None)  
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.listing_user = request.user
        form.save()
        form = ListingsForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "auctions/create.html", context)
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I'll need to look into what `form.instance` does because I definitely did similar things to this, but was obviously missing that key component.